# copying the attachment mails in outlook to GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, outlook, attachment, google-cloud-storage

As part of an automation procedure, I must copy the emails with attachments from Outlook to GCS(attachment formats should be .csv files). Can somebody advise me on how to complete this process best? Please keep in mind that I am new to GCP and that the simplest explanation would be beneficial.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say Outlook do you mean Exchange accounts (for example, Office365)?

Comment: Or do you need to automate Outlook and retrieve all attachments from the local storage/accounts configured in Outlook?

Comment: Please let me know the process of the second case like the outlook account configured in outlook and automating the attachments from outlook. Really sorry for the confusion and it's new area for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please ask specific question in new threads so readers could recognize Q&A easily.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Actually, the comes from one of our clients. Every day, we receive CSV files as attachments, and we require those files in GCS to continue. In other words, the entire process needs to be automated. We were stuck because it was on a separate platform.

Comment: The answer corresponds to the question and your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API such as Graph API to retrieve the required data from the Office365 side and transfer it to the GCS. See [Use the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) for more information.

In case of dealing with Outlook (as an application installed) you can develop a VBA, COM add-in or just automate Outlook from an external application.

The simplest choice is VBA which allows to automate tasks in Outlook. VBA macros are not designed for distributing on multiple machines, that is for COM add-ins were invented. In that case you can create an installer like for any other distributable software.

The Outlook object model provides a rich set of properties and methods that allows getting the job done. You can use the [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method to save attached files on the disk from where you could upload them to the GCS.